# What does "Warning : No return statement in function returning non-void" mean?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, nodes

This function creates a new node for a circular linked list,as shown:

```
Node *newNode(int data) 
{
  Node *temp = new Node;
  temp->next = temp;
  temp->data = data;
}
```

However, I am getting a warning from the compiler. I know it should have a return value but am not sure of the correct way to implement it. I'd be grateful for any help regarding this.

Comment: I don't see a `return temp;` at the end of that function, so maybe the compiler is on to something. By declaring `Node *` as the result type you are promising that *all* code paths eventually lead to `return`-ing a `Node *`. You code fails to deliver on that promise; thus the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined by

```
Node *newNode(int data)
```

your function is expected to return a Node pointer. However your implementation has no such return. The compiler warns you about this problem. A priori you can fix the problem by:

```
Node *newNode(int data) 
{ 
Node *temp = new Node; 
temp->next = temp; 
temp->data = data;
return temp; 
}
```

**Note:** this is quite a serious problem and you must fix your code, otherwise you have an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`Node *newNode(int data)` means this function has to return a `Node*`, which it doesn't, and that causes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). What you probably meant to do is adding `return temp` at the end of the function. Otherwise you leak memory anyway.

Fix:

```
Node *newNode(int data) 
{
  Node *temp = new Node;
  temp->next = temp;
  temp->data = data;
  return temp;
}
```

To actually fix this function, consider using smart pointers, so someone definitely and explicitly owns the heap-allocated object:

```
#include <memory>

struct Node {
  Node* next;
  int data;
};

[[nodiscard]] auto newNode(int const data) {
  auto temp  = std::make_unique<Node>();
  temp->next = temp.get();
  temp->data = data;
  return temp;
}
```